# Intellij Idea 2017.3 (and Android studio 3.1) project tool window doesn't show visibility icons anymore

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

After upgrading to Intellij Idea 2017.3 and to Android Studio 3.1 canary 6 I noticed the project tool window doesn't show the little lock icons next to files anymore.
This is very useful to have a bird's eye view on the visibility of each file (public, package protected...).

Is there a setting to bring them back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marco, please check this comment on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-172513#comment=27-2150075